# Computer-based alternatives to TI89 calculator?

Tags: online-resources, calculator

Back in the 90s in order to solve complex algebraic equations I would use my TI-89 calculator. What is a PC or Mac or iPhone or Internet-based equivalent?

I need to solve an equation like the following:

```
25000x^0.293150685 + 250000x - 298082 = 0
```

I tried the Desmos iPhone app and it said it didn't solve algebraic equations yet. It's 2017, let's get with the times already!

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25000x%5E0.293150685+%2B+250000x+-+298082+%3D+0&t=crmtb01 Wolfram Alpha also has an app for iPhone

Comment: It's andoid or linux :) e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Bisha.TI89Emu&hl=en or http://www.sagemath.org/

Answer (score 0):

SAGE! You should give very serious consideration to SAGE. There's a free online version which is superb. You can use it on your iPhone, tablet, or computer.

There is also a software package you can download and install.

I recommend SAGE as the default calculator for my classes. It's perfect for getting experience with Python, checking your work, or having it do work for you. It can integrate with GAP, Haskell, and so much more.

http://www.sagemath.org

Comment: I tried SageMath, but when I tried to write a program to solve the algebraic equation in my original question, it froze and never could solve it. Maybe I was doing it wrong. Can you give me the right program code?

Comment: Let me see your code, then I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Actually it was just a command: solve([0 == (250000*x^365) + (25000 * x^107) - 289082], x)

Comment: https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/82478ca9-aa05-4399-bb6e-bc6140d905c7/files/Stack%20ex.sagews

Via: https://ask.sagemath.org/question/7823/numerically-find-all-roots-in-an-interval/